# Change logo on the navigation menu when scrolling in odoo

Tags: jquery, navigation, odoo-12

I'm trying to change the navigation logo to dark version when scrolling. I see that the header has class .affixed when I scroll so I tried to change it like this using jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

if ($( "header .o_header_affix" ).hasClass("affixed")) {
$( ".navbar .navbar-brand img" ).attr( "src","http://placehold.it/220?text=Original+Logo!" );
}

});
```

this is how the HTML markup looks like:

https://prnt.sc/o1t81i

but it doesn't work. any help would be appreciated!

however, when i try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$( ".navbar .navbar-brand img" ).attr( "src","http://placehold.it/220?text=Original+Logo!" );

});
```

it works but it changes the logo everywhere, while I want to change it only after I scroll, so when the header has the class .affixed

where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'header' from the if statement.

```
if ($( ".o_header_affix" ).hasClass("affixed")) {
$( ".navbar .navbar-brand img" ).attr( "src","http://placehold.it/220?text=Original+Logo!" );
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/carlos_27/mufLbhpg/3/

Comment: in that case, you problem is somewhere else.. Maybe add the full html or a link where we can see exactly how the code works. I updated my answer with a fiddle to show that the if statement works correctly

Answer (score 0):

the HTML markup in odoo is so complicated, however i found a simple css solution for this if in case someone needs it.

```
.affixed .navbar a.navbar-brand {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/220?text=Original+Logo!");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  background-size: contain;

}

#wrapwrap .o_header_affix.affixed .navbar .navbar-brand img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```